# Memory allocation in MPI programs

Tags: memory-management, message-passing

How is memory allocated in slave nodes for execution of MPI programs ? How do slave nodes know the amount of memory to reserve ? What happens when a slave node can't find the data that it wants to access ?

This is not a homework problem , but a question that I tried came up in my mind and could'nt find on googling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a non-specific question, the best answer you can expect will also be non-specific

When programming using MPI you typically write a single program which is launched (via mpirun/mpiexec, or some batching system eg. torque) on a set of notes.

The master-slave model is but one approach.

The memory allocation is typically under program control, just as you would in any application allocate memory as needed, so to in your MPI program.

As to finding the data, it is often provided to them (directly or indirectly) (by the master
process, if the master-slave model is used). If indeed each MPI instance has to "search" for the data it is to be processing, then as with any program that is unable to find what it requires, it should send a suitable error message/status back to the caller (or the master process)

.PMCD.

Comment: Thanks ! The  MPI slave nodes obtain an image of the master process at runtime , right ? So i expect the slave processes to allocate memory for the variables locally. But my qstn is how do the proceses decide the size of memory to be allocated for the process . In other words how is the address space determined ? How is the information regarding the address space determined ?

Comment: The slave processes (instances of the MPI program) are just like any other program. If they are given a file name for the image they are to process, then the library routine used to open the image file will know how to inspect the file format to discover the image properties (pixel dimensions,color depth,metadata ...) and dynamically allocate required memory (eg. malloc/new). Then depending on the processing being done, your application should know if it needs to create another similar sized image (eg. the resulting image) and again can use the image library routines to allocate/construct one.